# From 360 video to Virtual world

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

IS it possible to convert a 360 video into a VR World ? Let's say i take a 360 video of my room, convert it into a 360 VR world and user with a headset can click on a chair in my room to know the details ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is when you put the 360 degree picture or video of your room, place GameObjects in the line of sight from the camera towards the object outside the sphere on which the photo/ video is playing. Then attach all the interactions you want on those game objects so that when your raycaster interact with the GameObjects your desired functions get done, like for example the details appear on another canvas which is just above your chair. Look at the attached picture, I've placed the red sphere which is my gameObject used as an event trigger to perform a change scene function when a user looks at an object in the video which is exactly in the line of sight of camera to red sphere.

[image]